# Solr auto suggestions with faceted search

Tags: solr, autocomplete, lucene, autosuggest

Is it possible to use Solr faceted search and return the whole field where the input is found?

`AnalyzingInfixSuggester` can return whole field but what I also need is term count for each suggestion which the suggester can't provide.

Comment: We would need to see your schema and config. How do you tokenize this input ? Can you elaborate on your final objective / the nature of this input ?

Please provide more information.

Alternatively, the Solr spellchecker might do what you want with the right set of options and if you tokenize the whole input as a single token. I havent seen the suggester returning term count, but Im certain the spellchecker does.

Comment: @SamuelFaure, let's consider there is no specific schema/solrconfig xml to start with. I am just wondering if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to return the whole field : just tokenize the whole field as one single token.

In my `schema.xml` (modified from sunspot-solr config) I have the following fields :

```xml
<dynamicField name="*_text" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="autocomplete" stored="true" type="autocomplete" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<copyField source="*_text"  dest="autocomplete" />
```

And this tokenizer :

```xml
<fieldType name="autocomplete" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

As you can see, the autocomplete field tokenizes the whole string as a single token, with the use of KeywordTokenizerFactory. The autocompleter will therefore return the whole string when requested.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think that with this configuration only documents that match the first term in the indexed field will be returned (no infix search).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a whole field, let's say a string, you look for a word in this string, you want solr to return the whole string ?